# Which selector would be executed?

Tags: css

CSS

```
#header #site_title_section {
float: left;
width: 300px;   
margin-left: 30px;
text-align: center;

 #site_title_section #site_title {
margin-top: 30px;
padding: 10px 0;
font-size: 40px; 
color: #4379ab;
font-weight: bold;
    }

 #site_title_section #salogon {
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 color: #333333;
  }
```

Html

```
    <div id="site_title_section">

        <div id="site_title">
          Professional
        </div>

        <div id="salogon">
            New Media Company</div>
        <div class="cleaner">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>
```

Could someone help me understand this

From the CSS codes "site_title_section" has appeared three times so when called in html  codes which one would be executed?

Comment: Put a minimal example of jsfiddle.net

Comment: Do u have any tag with `id=header` as a parent to `<div id="site_title_section">` in your html?

Answer (score 0):

First note there is a small error in your code:

```
#header #site_title_section {
   float: left;
   width: 300px;   
   margin-left: 30px;
   text-align: center;
} /* <-- You forgot this */
```

Now to how CSS is read it goes like this:

```
[parent] [child1] [child of child1] ... { .. }
```

So for example think of it as going into the element in the HTML code. For example:

```
<div id="site_title_section"> <!-- #site_title_section part -->

    <div id="site_title"> <!-- #site_title_section #site_title -->
      Professional
    </div>

    <div id="salogon"> <!-- #site_title_section #salogon -->
        New Media Company</div>
    <div class="cleaner">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

For `#header #site_title_section`, at least from the code that is shown. Even know we have `#site_title_section` inside. There is no parent with the id `#header`, so this does nothing. But supposed there was (you may have just forgot to paste it). Then it would effect the entire `#site_title_section` div.

**[Here is a fiddle with all your CSS affects (including an added header)](http://jsfiddle.net/zxzsLcrw/1/)**